# How to get nearest highest multiple of 9 in java

Tags: java, math

I need something that can calculate the nearest highest multiple of 9. So for example, if I input 1 into this function it will return 9, if I input 10 into this function it will return 18 and so on.

I've tried this `9*(Math.round(number/9))` and `9*(Math.ceil(Math.abs(number/9)))` but they return the nearest multiple of 9, so if you input 10 into this function it will return 9, for my purposes it will need to return 18. (There's probably a better way to say this other then "nearest highest")

If anyone can help me that will be great!

Comment: 9 _is_ the nearest multiple of 9 of 10 though... Is 9 not nearer to 10 than 18?

Comment: How about adding 1 to the result of `Math.ceil` and then multiplying to 9.

Comment: @Sweeper once a number exceeds the multiple it needs to return the next multiple. So if you input 9, it will return 9 but once you get to 10 it will return 18, once you get to 19 it will return 27 and so on. I'm not the best at wording things so sorry if you don't understand.

Comment: What about negative numbers? Does -10 output -9 or -18?

Comment: @Sweeper negative numbers are not a concern in my use case, I only need positive numbers.

Comment: You should try `9*(Math.ceil(Math.abs(number/(double)9)))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rounding up a number to nearest 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173762/rounding-up-a-number-to-nearest-9)

Comment: @AtomCraft what happens if the user enters 9 or 18? What shall the algorithm return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula.

```
number + (9 - (number % 9))
```

And for the exceptional case when the number is a multiple of 9, use a condition:

```
int result = number % 9 == 0 ? number : number + (9 - (number % 9));
```

Comment: This is the most elegant for me, I've edited by adding the edge case when the number is already a multiple of 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a multiplier whose value depends on whether number is multiple of 9 or not. Check below code:

```
int number = 10;
Double ceilValue = Math.ceil(number/9);
double multiplier = 0.0;
if (number % 9 == 0) {
    multiplier = ceilValue;
} else {
    multiplier = ceilValue + 1;
}
Double result = 9 * multiplier;

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:`18.0`

Comment: I have edited to include sample output as well. Also, checked with different outputs and it seems to be giving correct result.

Comment: Sorry removed my previous comment, realised it was a typo. Sorry!

Comment: This works but I would try and avoid floating point math. I believe @hossein-rasekhi solution below is more elegant and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one (max) 9 times and check if it is a multiple of 9 like so:

```java
int x = 9;
int result = 0;

for (int i = x; i < 9; i++)
{
    if (i % 9 == 0)
    {
        result = i;
        break;
    }
}

// result will contains the 'nearest' 'highest' or it self multiple of 9
```